# Admin menu and dashboard not showing

Tags: admin, magento-1.5, magento-1.5.1

I am using Magento 1.5 and have just updated the ebizmarts mailchimp plugin.  When I returned to the admin the menu and page is blank except for the page header.

I have logged out and back in again and cleared the cache manually but with no luck.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have enough rep to do simple comment but if you have access to the Apache log check that to see any errors related to the admin panel.

Does setting "false" in app/etc/modules/ebizmarts mailchimp plugin xml extensions bring back the dashboard? (May need to refresh cache again to reset etc/modules)

Seems like if its failing at the page header point its probably related to ebizmart menu item either via adminhtml.xml or adminhtml node in config.xml

Comment: Thank you @Bennith that worked fine, disabling the extension and clearing the cache again did the trick.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Though the ebizmart plugin wont be functional due to it being disabled(set to false).